# grep greater than an integer in file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt and file4.txt

Tags: grep

I am trying to find anomalies in some text files that have a list of integers. is there a way to search inside multiple files for a number greater than x?

Comment: Yes, it is with `awk` for example. Show some sample input and some of your attempts...

Comment: This is how i was able to get my desired results, I am trying to find ping anomalies over 1000ms
only files i wish to search are in the folder i am working in

cat * | egrep 'time=........ ms|time=......... ms'

this is pretty basic but works for my needs. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: You can also use directly `egrep 'time=........ ms|time=......... ms' *`, no need to `cat`.

Comment: am using cat to parse multiple files
cat testfile* |egrep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to find ping anomalies over 1000ms, the only files I wish to search are in the folder I am working in. This is how I was able to get my desired results:

```
cat * | egrep 'time=........ ms|time=......... ms'
```

This is pretty basic but works for my needs.

Comment: Was actually a self-answer with a thank you tacked on the end, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
alex@porcellino:/tmp/test$ ls
a  b
alex@porcellino:/tmp/test$ cat a
1
2
16
4
7
alex@porcellino:/tmp/test$ cat b
5
6
89
11
alex@porcellino:/tmp/test$ for n in `cat * | sort | uniq`;do if [ $n -gt 12 ];then grep $n *;fi;done
a:16
b:89
```

Comment: for n in `cat * | sort | uniq`;do if [ $n -gt 100.000  ];then grep $n *;fi;done

    -bash: [: 100.000: integer expression expected
    -bash: [: 10:06:42: integer expression expected
    -bash: [: EST: integer expression expected
    -bash: [: 2014:: integer expression expected
    -bash: [: 100.000: integer expression expected

Comment: I am trying to find anomalies in ping responses
    Tue Feb  4 10:04:36 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=756 ttl=50 time=78.726 ms
    Tue Feb  4 10:04:37 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=757 ttl=50 time=102.009 ms
    Tue Feb  4 10:04:38 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=758 ttl=50 time=21.964 ms
    Tue Feb  4 10:04:39 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=759 ttl=50 time=45.387 ms
    Tue Feb  4 10:04:40 EST 2014: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=760 ttl=50 time=68.818 ms